# ggsave mac .png ignores size

Tags: r, ggplot2, xlsx, ggsave

On my Macbook Pro, early 2015, running High Sierra (if that matters) - it appears as though ggsave ignores my image width and height specification for .png files. I do not have this problem on machines running Windows. Here's a little reproducible example, although again, this issue will not occur if you are running Windows:

```
# Setup Workspace
library("xlsx")
library("ggplot2")

# Generate Data
plotData <- data.frame(
  x = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
  y = c(5,8,3,9)
)

# Create Plot
p <- ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = plotData, aes(x,y), stat = "identity")
ggsave("example.png", width = 4, height = 3, units = "in")

#Add Plot to Workbook
wb <- createWorkbook(type = "xlsx")
sheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = "Example")
addPicture(file.path(getwd(), "example.png"), sheet, scale = 1, startRow = 3,
           startColumn = 2)
saveWorkbook(wb, file.path(getwd(),"example.xlsx"))
```

Is there a way to fix this issue with ggsave, if that's the problem? If not, can someone suggest an alternative method to save plots with a specific size to add to a workbook with the xlsx package that will work across both Mac and Windows machines?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is there no difference between: `ggsave("example.png", width = 4, height = 3, units = "in")` and
`ggsave("example.png", width = 8, height = 6, units = "in")`

Comment: I can't reproduce on my Mac (Sierra, `R 3.4.0`, `ggplot2_2.2.1.9000`); based on OPs example, `ggsave` with different `width`s produces images of different size.

Comment: so then the issue is not ggsave.

Comment: Thank you both so much for trying to reproduce this! Great idea to test different sizes to see if it responds -- the resulting image size is different when ggsave is passed width = 8 and height = 6. Unfortunately, I'm still not sure what the issue is and what the best cross platform solution might be.

Comment: If I run ggsave with dpi = 72 the resulting png has the correct dimensions in inches. However, I'd really like to use higher resolution for print. Resizing the images after the script has run is not a good option sadly.

Comment: @KrisWilliams Not sure what you mean by "cross platform solution". `ggsave` will produce images with the same dimension/resolution on Windows/Unix machines if you use the same parameters. **So there is 100% compatibility.** Why not save as PDF instead of PNG, which produces a vector graphic and scales without loss of quality & pixelation.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Yes, I think the issue has to do with something other than `ggsave`. What I mean by "cross platform solution" is a solution that will work across different computers with different operating systems (Mac and Windows). I had the same thought about using an alternative file format, PDF saves with the correct dimensions, but sadly does not seem to work with `addPicture` from the xlsx package - trading one issue for another.

Comment: I really appreciate everyone trying to help with my strange issue here. For now I'll stick with 72 dpi .png files on the Macbook -- if others have ideas for what might be causing this issue, i'd be curious to learn!

Comment: `addPicture(file.path(getwd(), "example.png"), sheet, scale = 1, startRow = 3, startColumn = 2)` maybe adjust the scale parameter?